# Compilation Error for extern variable initialized in other file

Tags: c

I have these two different program  where I want to access the static variable declared in program1 from program2.

Program1. (
    /* file  a.c */)

```
#include<stdio.h>    

static int a = 100; /* global static variable not visible outside this file.*/
int *b = &a; /* global int pointer, pointing to global static*/
```

Program2

```
#include<stdio.h>
/* file b.c */
extern int *b; /* only declaration, b is defined in other file.*/

int main()
{
        printf("%d\n",*b); /* dereferencing b will give the value of variable a in file a.c */
        return 0;
}
```

While I compile program1 , gcc a.c , no compilation error, but while I compile program2 ( gcc b.c) I am getting compilation error .

```
test_b.c:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `b'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why there is compile error ? Here is the link of program [static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973162/static-variable)

Thanks in advance.

***EDIT 1:***

My intention to use static variable from other program. I thought every .c program must have main() function and only .h program have declaration , I am wrong at that point. So I remove main() function from a.c program and instead of compiling two different program separately , now I compile only once using gcc a.c b.c as per suggestion of Filip. Now it's working fine. Thanks all of you.

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?

Comment: You cannot have one program access variables from another program with the extern keyword. See this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856636/effects-of-the-extern-keyword-on-c-functions) that explains pretty well what the extern keyword is used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to link against `a.c` while compiling `b.c`:

`gcc a.c b.c`

You can't expect the linker to magically find the C file where `b` is defined. `extern` means it is defined elsewhere - you have to say where. By compiling and linking with `a.c`, the linker can now find a declaration for `b`.

Of course, you can't have 2 `main()` functions.

Comment: The `main()` definitions would clash.

Comment: @ Filipe , thanks. I remove main from a.c and now it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code already said it. `b.cpp` only has a declaration, not a definition, of the symbol in question.

Since these are clearly meant to be source files from two separate projects, I would suggest moving your definition to its *own* `.cpp` file which may then be shared between the two projects.

```
$ gcc a.c myIntPointerIsHere.c
$ gcc b.c myIntPointerIsHere.c
```

However, there are clearer ways to share code between two different projects.

Comment: I want to use the static variable of a.c program from b.c . your suggestion is to define my own program with these definition . will myIntPointerIsHere.c hold all the variables I need to use ?

Answer (score -1):

The both modules contain the definition of main. It seems that the compiler did not include the first module in your project. Otherwise I think it would issue an error that main was redefined.

Comment: Look at his build commands. He is building one at a time, deliberately. It's deliberate because these are separate projects. You can tell from the multiple use of `int main()`. And from the opening statement: _"two different program"_

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit He said nothing about building  a project. He said about compilation of modules. They are different things.

Comment: He didn't say "modules". He has two _programs_. In fact, it is quite clear from the question what the intention is. Please go ahead and read it again now.

Comment: @ Lightness Races in Orbit No, it is totally unclear whether he is going to join these two modules in one project.

Comment: I refer you to my comment on your previous question, wherein I asked you to use SO notification syntax properly instead of mangling it with random spaces. It's _entirely_ clear, because he actually showed us his build commands. They're right there in the question, for your delectation.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit No, it is unclear because if he is not going to join these modules together then the question has no any sense.

Comment: Code sharing between projects, more even more than one executable output within a single project, which is hardly unusual! It's not rocket science. But I'll leave you to your doubts.